# How to override property "Binding Operation" in SoapRequestNode iib?

Tags: esb, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am consuming a web service in IBM integration toolkit having multiple operations. How can I change the binding operation property dynamically at run time so that same SoapRequestNode can be used for all operations?

Answer (score 1):

Set the operation in the [Local Environment](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac56192_.htm):

```
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.SOAP.Request.Operation = 'myOperation';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Setting the Value Runtime can be achieved through your ESQL code before SOAPRequest Node.
Just assign the below field with required Operation as per requirement

SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.SOAP.Request.Operation = 'requiredOperation';